# Dropzone.js and form validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, forms, validation, dropzone.js

Is it possible not to break the nice Rails form validation errors displayed after marking the whole form the 'dropzone' class?

Now, when I try to submit the form, nothing changes and the page stays at it was without providing any info for user which fields doesn't meet the requirements. Controller renders JSON response (dropzone using consequence) which seems to not be processed by the view.

Thank you in advance for your quick response.

Comment: You need to parse the JSON response into your js callback yourself. Let us know if you need help with that.

Comment: Ok, in what dropzone listner should I parse the JSON response and how to pass it to the Rails form in order to show the input errors correctly?

Comment: take a look at this event: http://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-success

Comment: please see my answer. let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

My workaround for this problem:

```
Dropzone.options.filedrop = {
    init: function () {
        // Other triggers not listed
        // ...

        this.on("error", function (file, response) {
            // Gets triggered when the files have successfully been sent.
            // Redirect user or notify of success.

            // Build an unordered list from the list of errors
            var _ref, _results, _i, _len;
            if ($.isPlainObject(response)) { // Check if response is in JSON format for showing standard form errors
                // Remove errors from accepted image
                file.previewElement.classList.remove("dz-error");
                _ref = file.previewElement.querySelectorAll("[data-dz-errormessage]");
                _results = [];
                for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
                    node = _ref[_i];
                    _results.push(node.textContent = null);
                }

                file['status'] = 'success';
                console.log("acceptedImage: " + JSON.stringify(file));

                var json = response;
                var errorText = "<div id=\"error_explanation\"><h2>" + Object.keys(json).length + " errors prohibited this thing from being saved:</h2><ul>";
                $.each(json, function (key, value) {
                    errorText += "<li>" + key.capitalize() + ' ' + value[0] + "</li> ";
                });
                errorText += "</ul></div>";
                console.log("errorText: " + errorText);

                // Insert error list into form
                $('.errors_placeholder').html(errorText);
            } else {
                if (myDropzone.files.length > 1) {
                    myDropzone.removeFile(myDropzone.files[0]);
                }
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the JSON response into your js callback yourself, something like this:

```
   Dropzone.options.filedrop = {
      init: function () {
        this.on("complete", function (file, jsonResponse) {
          console.log(jsonResponse);
          //do stuff with the jsonResponse here
        });
      }
    };
```

Comment: Thank you, I figured it out myself but used `error` event instead. Is there any way to pass the errors directly to the form and omit rendering the errors section from scratch in JS?

Comment: @Kaktusiarz can you please update your code to show how you handled this?

Comment: @Kaktusiarz can you please help with this topic - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39056366/how-do-i-render-photo-errors-with-json-using-dropzone-js-in-rails-4